# Better data structure than HashTable to keep track of processed records?

Tags: java, android, data-structures, hash

I'm processing a large number of database records, each with a unique key.

Due to the nature of my database, my processing method may encounter the same key twice since it is a relational database and one record may have more than one "parent" record.

It is a waste of precious time, processing power, memory, and file size to process records multiple times.  Thus I need a way to keep a record of which ids I have already processed.

I have looked at HashTable, since it is O(1) for get and put functions and those are the only functions I need.  However it seems like a waste of memory to have essentially a (1000+)/Load Factor chunk of memory essentially storing boolean values.  Plus I don't know my desired capacity and would have to put up with a lot of rehashes or allocated a lot more memory than I need.

I think am looking for a data structure that you can add a value to it and have it give an error of some kind if the id already exists in the collection, like returning false from the `put(T value)` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it sounds like you want a set, not a table.

Second, if you want O(1), your only option is a HashSet, with the memory overhead.  If you're willing to go with O(log(n)), then a TreeSet will work just fine, sans overhead.

Third, set's add(T t) will return false if the element is already present.  Sounds like you *really* want a set instead of a table.

O(log(n)) is still pretty fast.  It certainly isn't O(1), but it's none too shabby.  You just need to decided (perhaps after some testing) which one is right for you.

Comment: O(1) is a benefit of HashSet, not a requirement of the problem.  Sorry that was not clear

Comment: Sounds like the Set is exactly what I needed.  Now I just need to decide if O(log(n)) vs O(1) is more important than using up extra memory.

Answer (score 2):

I think HashSet is what you're looking for:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: Hashtable is a `<K, V>` pair while HashSet is a "list" per-say. How can it help the OP?

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman I only need to keep track of the ids that have been processed, not map the ids to their database records.  Thus HashSet is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [Bloom filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter),instead of the hashmap.It's a probabilistic data-structure.The problem with Bloom filter is that it will give false +ve's.Check out this [implementation of bloom filter](http://code.google.com/p/java-bloomfilter/).This would be the memory efficient and faster solution than a hashmap.

**More Info on Bloom filter:**

- [What problems have you solved using bloom filters?[SO Question]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3075301/306855)
- [Bloom Filter : Variants & Applications[Blog]](http://appolo85.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/bloom-filter/)
- [Using a bloom filter to optimize a SQL query](http://asemanfar.com/Using-a-bloom-filter-to-optimize-a-SQL-query)

Comment: Interesting, I had never heard of this before.  Still, I need absolute certainty, not probability.  If I get a false positive, that record may never be processed.  If it instead gave false negatives, that might work but would be not much more efficient than just processing records multiple times in the first place.

Comment: @CodeFusionMobile: I'm not quite sure how to exactly use them.The main application is for spelling correction.Also I've read google bigtables(google's database) use bloom-filter for optimization.

Comment: The consequence of a false positive means a record is processed again: so extra time? You can use a bloom filter (or scalable bloom filter if you don't know how many records you'll insert) to maintain a specific error probability. The question is, whats more expensive? The bloom solution `k*O(1) + <probability of failure>*k*<process cost>`? Or the Set solution `k*O(log(n))`? If the cost to process on record is sufficiently low, I think you could tune your bloom filter beat the set even in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hey,
since you are working with a data base could you not just store this information in a secondary database table or with the records? Also if you are having a Tree structure (since you are talking about parents) why not use a tree traversing algorithm, that marks processed nodes. 
Checkout these [Breadth First Search/Depth First Search Animations](http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/~skiena/combinatorica/animations/search.html) and these to Wikipeadia Entries on [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) and [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

In general I would make sure to track the processing flag with the Object/Row. Instead of a separate data structure.

Comment: The database relationship was simplified in the OP because it wasn't relevant. The relationship model is not a simple tree.  Also, since I am working on the Android platform, Database operations are relatively expensive since they usually require a write to flash memory.  Using the tree model as an example, I have several leafs in the tree (different parents) that are acutally the same database record (same child).  This is a graph, not a tree, and traversal becomes much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If the resultset is ordered properly, could you just keep the "last processed" id in memory?  That way, you just have to check the "current id" vs the "last id" - if they're different, process away, otherwise skip to the next record?

Comment: The records are processed in separate chunks from different queries and result sets from the same table, so this option is not feasible.